# TAB breaks element position

Tags: html, css

I made jsfiddle example over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FE55W/

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide n1"><a href="#">test</a></div>
        <div class="slide n2"><a href="#">test</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    width:500px;
    height:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slider{
    width:5000px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.slide{
    width:500px;
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
}
.slide.n1{
    background-color: green;
}
.slide.n2{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Problem is when you click with the mouse on green square and push TAB several times, blue square appears and breaks elemets position. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: add `tabindex="-1"` to the blue anchor tag http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/FE55W/1/

Comment: @PedroEstrada: That seems to be the answer. Are you writing up a full answer or leaving it for somebody else to do?

Comment: @PedroEstrada Common Pedro! Do it! :) This is correct answer.

Comment: I'm doing it, I'm doing it!

Comment: But the case is interesting,just fixing without knowing is no fun :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `tabindex="-1"` to the anchor that you don't want to TAB to.

```
<div class="slide n2"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">test</a></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/FE55W/1/